# nginx in place of apach2 php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I was working under LAMP stack on my laptop an decided to use nginx in place of apache2 (LEMP)

Installed nginx, php5-fpm and fast-cgi without removing any thing from LAMP stack

Stopped apache2 and started nginx trying localhost (shows server not found)

Means nginx didn't install successfully and i found that the folder

/etc/php5/{apache2  cgi  cli  conf.d  fpm}

so which folder is unneeded especially (cgi cli fpm) and what configuration needed ?

-when restarting nginx I got that messgae:
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_pass" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default~:70
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Answer (score 0):

the

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default~
```

is the give away.. chances are the editor you used makes a backup and appends ~ to the end. Nginx will load everything in the sites-enabled directory so it's loading default and default~ which are probably the same.

Delete

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default~
```

Then a start should work

Comment: thanks it work but localhot shows forbidden and 500 internal server error for localhost/site